# How to fix that an invoke after a piece of audio causes the audio to be delayed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, invoke

In my first game that I'm currently working on, I'm trying to make a piece of audio and an explosion animation to happen when a player dies. I got it to work perfectly fine. Right after the line of code that makes the audio play, I used an invoke to delay the respawn. This caused the following issue: The animation plays, but without any sound. Next, the player respawns after the delay and only after the delay, does my audio play.

I haven't been able to come up with any way of fixing this (I recently began coding with unity, so I don't know a lot of options).
This is the code that executes when player 1 dies:

```
   public void LoseLifeP1()
{
    Debug.Log("Player1 died");
    playerNumber = 1;
    FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("PlayerDeath");
    Respawn(playerNumber);
}

public void Respawn(int playernumber)
{
    if (playerNumber == 1)
    {
        Invoke("waiter1", 1.5f);
    }
}

public void waiter1()
{
    Player1.transform.position = spawnpoint2.transform.position;
    Player1.transform.rotation = spawnpoint2.transform.rotation;
    Player1.velocity = speed;
}
```

So even though you can see that the audio is supposed to play before the respawn, it plays after the respawn. How would I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you spin up a new thread and invoke `waiter1` a few milliseconds later?

Comment: @mjwillis how would do that? (I'm still a beginner, so I have no idea)